# Cloudfront origin change

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a cloudfront distribution with 2 origins from S3 bucket (name: website and maintenance),and I need to make sure that if my website is down or under maintenance then content from one of the origins (maintenance) is shown to the users. How to make that change? Please help me as I am new to AWS.

Answer (score 0):

set primary/secondary origin and failover rules in origin group ( http response 5xx, 4xx )